# SQL COUNT AS XXX

Tags: asp.net, sql, count

I am trying to select user followers.As

```
SELECT     
profil_id, 
profil_user_id, 
profil_fullname, 
profil_puan, 
profil_aciklama, 
UserId,
UserName
COUNT(select follower_id  from follow where followed_id='2') as follower

FROM         
profil ,aspnet_Users
WHERE
profil_user_id ='2' and
profil.profil_user_id=aspnet_Users.UserID
```

I want to select followers count but  its not working.Error :**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
**
where is the problem ? (ı DONT WANT TO USE LEFT JOIN IT HAS ISSUE)

Comment: seems to me that you are missing a comma after userName.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a `,` after `UserName`

```
UserName // <-- missed ',' here
COUNT(select follower_id  from follow where followed_id='2') as follower
```

Also, this is not valid a valid sql server query

```
COUNT(select follower_id  from follow where followed_id='2') as follower
```

A valid option would be following Danila´s code

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
COUNT(select follower_id  from follow where followed_id='2') as follower
```

with

```
(select COUNT(follower_id)  from follow where followed_id='2') as follower
```

Comment: now error 2 :D Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: owww sorry its solved my problem with Claudio Redi answer.thanks